# VBA modify url link so it pulls data from today

Tags: vba, urlencode

I am new to VBA and trying to create a module where data will be pulled on a daily bases and would like url link in the module to update automatically to today's date. How should I change current url? I assume I need to change only this part: 2021%2F11%2F23 . Appreciate any feedback

```
website = "https://fclm-portal.amazon.com/reports/processPathRollup?reportFormat=HTML&warehouseId=&maxIntradayDays=1&spanType=Intraday&startDateIntraday=2021%2F11%2F23&startHourIntraday=7&startMinuteIntraday=30&endDateIntraday=2021%2F11%2F23&endHourIntraday=18&endMinuteIntraday=0&_adjustPlanHours=on&_hideEmptyLineItems=on&employmentType=AllEmployees"
```

**EDIT**: now getting "Object variable or with block variable not set" on line `ObVolume = ...`

```vb
Dim response As String 

Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP") 
request.Open "GET", website, False 
request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT" request.send 

response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode) 
html.body.innerHTML = response 
ObVolume = html.getElementsByClassName("actualVolume numeric").Item(172).innerText
```

Answer (score 1):

`Application.EncodeURL(Format(date,"yyyy/mm/dd"))` will give you the part you need.

So:

```vb
website = "https://fclm-portal.amazon.com/reports/processPathRollup?" & _
     "reportFormat=HTML&warehouseId=&maxIntradayDays=1&spanType=Intraday&" & _
     "startDateIntraday=2021%2F11%2F23&startHourIntraday=7&startMinuteIntraday=30&" & _
     "endDateIntraday=<dt>&endHourIntraday=18&endMinuteIntraday=0&_adjustPlanHours=on&" & _
     "_hideEmptyLineItems=on&employmentType=AllEmployees"

website = Replace(website, "<dt>", Application.EncodeURL(Format(date,"yyyy/mm/dd")))
```

Comment: Thank you! I believe that helps with date but now my code throws runtime error 91, 


Any ideas on why this could be happening? All suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: What is the error *message* and which line throws the error?

Comment: "Object variable or with block variable not set". Tis is the code right after what you provided. The error is thrown for the line OBVolume :                                                                                             
Dim response As String
Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
request.Open "GET", website, False
request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
request.send
response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
html.body.innerHTML = response
ObVolume = html.getElementsByClassName("actualVolume numeric").Item(172).innerText

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there - it's difficult to read in a comment.

Comment: I don't see any declaration for `ObVolume` ?  What type of variable is that?  either you have it defined as some object type (which it should not be), or there's no element in the document which is matched by `html.getElementsByClassName("actualVolume numeric").Item(172)` and so you can't read the innerText property